# CSS row-fluid not responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I'm a beginner in html/css and I'm trying to create something that will go into a page of a platform called Chronus. The idea is for users to be able to click on one of the four choices which will take them to the relevant section in the platform so that they don't have keep 'going back' (a sort of nav, but not really). I've used 'row fluid' as per the code below. I also attach an image to show you how it looks in a desktop/laptop. The problem is, as the width of the device decreases, the div that all the links are in does not increase in height, so the second two links are cut off (also image attached).

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="background-color: #DEEBF9; color: #094183;">
<div class="footerlinks">
<div class="span3">
<p><a href="">Before the match</a></p>
<a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>

<div class="span3"><a href=""> </a>

<p><a href="">Career resources</a></p>
<a href=""> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>

<div class="span3"><a href=""> </a>

<p><a href="">The mentoring partnership</a></p>
<a href=""> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>

<div class="span3"><a href=""> </a>

<p><a href="">Partnership wrap up</a></p>
<a href=""> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>
</div>
</div>

<style>
.footerlinks {
text-align:center;
height: 160px;
vertical-align: middle;

padding: 40px;
font-family: ARIAL;
font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
```

[links in laptop/desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTDs1.png)
[links in narrow device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5smA.png)

Would anyone be able to suggest a solution for this please? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the height from `.footerlinks`. The reason it is happening is that when you see it from a narrow device, your content is more than 160px.

```
.footerlinks {
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 40px;
  font-family: ARIAL;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```